# Mouse movements not registering on Ubuntu laptop with new mouse (Thinkpad E590)

Tags: usb, mouse, touchpad

recently purchased a new mouse that works perfectly on my Mac, but when I plug it into my Ubuntu laptop (E590 ThinkPad), the computer doesn't seem to register any mouse movements. The right click and left click buttons, as well as the mouse wheel, work fine, but the cursor doesn't move when I move the mouse. I've tried plugging the mouse in and out, restarting the system, and using the following commands, but nothing seems to work:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I also have a Lenovo mouse that works fine with my laptop, so I think the computer is having trouble recognizing this specific mouse. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Thank you in advance for your help!